# Load SwipeView pages dynamically

Tags: qt, qml

I have created the following MWE (Qt 5.13.0):

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3

ApplicationWindow
{
    property int itemsNo: 3;

    id: window
    visible: true

    width: 480
    height: 480

    SwipeView
    {
        anchors.fill: parent;
        id: theSwipeView;

        Loader
        {
            sourceComponent: theSingleComp;

            Component
            {
                id: theSingleComp;

                Page
                {
                    Text
                    {
                        text: "The single one";
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Repeater
        {
            model: itemsNo;

            Loader
            {
                sourceComponent: theMultiComp;

                Component
                {
                    id: theMultiComp;

                    Page
                    {
                        Text
                        {
                            text: "The multi one " +
                                  (theSwipeView.currentIndex - 1);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my program, I have an unique component (`theSingleComp`) and multiple components behind him (`theMultiComp`). As for now, I need to implement the following functionality:

In case the model used for `theMultiComp` has only 1 item, display only this item and not the `theSingleComp`. In case the are more `theMultiComp` items, display it like now. It seems to me that there is no possibility for this to work if I keep the items defined statically. But on the other hand, I don't know how to do this dynamically, since there is a case in which one of the components should not be displayed at all. I tried an approach like this:

```
sourceComponent: (itemsNo > 1) ? theSingleComp : null;
```

But then the page for this null component is still created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `Loader` is an `Item` and `SwipeView` creates a page for it even if it doesn't have a source component.

To solve this problem you can use `Repeater` instead with a model of 1 (or 0 to disable it). `Repeater` is also an `Item` but it has some special code under the hood to be ignored by containers.

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3

ApplicationWindow
{
    id: window
    property int itemsNo: 0

    visible: true

    width: 480
    height: 480

    SwipeView {
        id: theSwipeView
        anchors.fill: parent
        Repeater {
            model: window.itemsNo > 1 ? 1 : 0
            Page {
                Text {
                    text: "The single one"
                }
            }
        }
        Repeater {
            model: window.itemsNo
            Page {
                Text {
                    text: "The multi one " + model.index
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(I've simplified your code to remove the explicit Components and the Loaders)

Comment: Thanks for help, perfect solution. The loaders were there because I copied the code pieces from my original code. The only thing that makes me wonder is why in this solution the application starts at second page (in case more than 1 page present)?

Comment: I guess because the single page is added after and the SwipeView doesn't change its index after its initalization.

Comment: Is there a way to force the order here (single repeater first)?

Comment: Ok, I kind of tricked it. The completion event of the first repeater Page triggers assigning of the model of the second repeater (second repeater model at startup is 0). Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with the following solution but I am not happy with it. It's very hacky and the user can see how the page index changes.

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3

ApplicationWindow
{
    property int itemsNo: 2;

    id: window
    visible: true

    width: 480
    height: 480

    SwipeView
    {
        anchors.fill: parent;
        id: theSwipeView;

        Component.onCompleted:
        {
            if (itemsNo > 1)
                insertItem(0, theSingleComp);

            set0IndexTimer.start();
        }

        Timer
        {
            id: set0IndexTimer;
            interval: 1;
            running: false;
            repeat: false;

            onTriggered: theSwipeView.setCurrentIndex(0);
        }

        onCurrentIndexChanged: console.log("page: ", currentIndex);

        Repeater
        {
            model: itemsNo;

            Loader
            {
                sourceComponent: theMultiComp;

                Component
                {
                    id: theMultiComp;

                    Page
                    {
                        Text
                        {
                            text: "The multi one " + theSwipeView.currentIndex;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    Item
    {
        id: theSingleComp;

        Page
        {
            Text
            {
                text: "The single one";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am still seeking some other examples.